# Can I change the duration of desktop window spread?

Tags: compiz, window, animations

Is it possible to change the animation duration of window spread using `compiz`? I want to make it a little slower but I can't seem to find it under the scale window options.

Comment: Doesn't lowering ccsm > Scale > Speed do what you want? (default is 5.0000

Comment: Oh, totally missed that. It's perfect! Thanks!